# Need a way for a web service running in an Azure Container Instance to determine the client IP address

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-instances

I have a web service running in a ACI and need a way to determine the client IP address.  It appears that there is a proxy fronting the instance as all connections are from 10.*.*.*.

There doesn't appear to be an X-Forwarded-For header in the request so I am at a loss as to how to determine client IP.